# CNN accuracy is not improving

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of images ( EEG spectrograms ) as given below
[image]

Image dimensions are 669X1026. I am using the following code for binary classification of the spectrograms.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K

# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 669, 1026

train_data_dir = '/home/spectrograms/train'
validation_data_dir = '/home/spectrograms/test'
nb_train_samples = 791
nb_validation_samples = 198
epochs = 100
batch_size = 3



if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height,3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(512, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(128, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(16))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0,
    zoom_range=0,
    horizontal_flip=False)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('CNN_model.h5')
```

But I am not able to get a training accuracy greater than 0.53. I have only a limited amount of data ( 790 training samples and 198 testing samples ). So increasing number of input images is not an option. What else can I do to improve the accuracy?

Comment: That's very low amount of data. You might make your model little bit more complex, then you should also regularize it. I would stick to transfer learning in this task actually. Also if you can do, try to increase batch size little bit more.

Comment: Can you explain how I can use transfer learning here? Also, is there any kind of algorithms or methods that are useful when working with a small dataset?

Comment: I am not sure if 'imagenet' contains such things like this but it does worth to try. It is hard to work with that kind of datasets. Maybe augmentation with opencv2 before training, might help.

Comment: Thanks. I will try

Comment: Try looking for any pretrained open-source model that has been trained on a similar purpose like yours, so that the data are similar, then you can do transfer learning with that.

Comment: You could tried with a simpler model first, just one or 2 layers, and reduce the number of filters. To improve accuracy you could try data augmentation technique, but it is to be applied with discernment regarding your specific use case or it will just impeded improvement.

Answer (score 0):

your code

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0,
    zoom_range=0,
    horizontal_flip=False)
```

Is not doing any image augmentation, only rescalling. Not sure what type of augmentation may help. Looks like your images really do not rely on color. It probably will not help accuracy but you could reduce computational expense by converting the images to gray scale. You might get some improvement by using the Keras callbacks ReduceLROnPlateau and EarlyStopping. Documentation is [here.](https://keras.io/api/callbacks/) My suggested code for these callbacks is shown below

```
rlronp=tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor="val_loss", factor=0.5, patience=1,
    verbose=1, mode="auto", min_delta=0.0001, cooldown=0, min_lr=0)
estop=tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", min_delta=0,patience=4,
    verbose=1, mode="auto", baseline=None, restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks=[rlronp, estop]
```

You can try using transfer learning. Most of those models are trained on the imagenet dataset which is dis-similar to the type of images you are using but it might be worth a try. I recommend you use the Mobilenet model. Code for that is shown below

```
base_model=tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False, 
           input_shape=input_shape, pooling='max', weights='imagenet',dropout=.4) 
x=base_model.output
x = Dense(64,activation='relu')(x)
x=Dropout(.3, seed=123)(x)
output=Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model=Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=output)        
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

use the callbacks referenced above in model.fit  You may get a warning the Mobilenet was trained with an image shape of 224 X 224 X 3 but it should still load the imagenet weights and work.